# Sort an array in custom alphabetical order

Tags: javascript

How do you sort an array like this:

```
['apple','very','auto','tom','tim','violet'....]
```

To get it ordered by v,a,t,x,b....etc (Not alphebetical)

```
['violet','very','auto','tom','tim',...]
```

In script, I'd do something like this:

```
myArray.sort('v','a','t'...)
```

How can I do it in JavaScript?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Something like this > Almost like an .orderby  

['violet','very','auto','tom','tim',...]

Comment: K cool got you my answer must work for you.

Comment: Thank you, learnt something new from yr syntax as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maintain an array of the letter precedence and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by the index of the first letter in this array.

This version puts any inputs that do *not* start with one of your ordered characters at the end of the sorted array, in regular (locale-sensitive) alphabetical order:

```
var order = ['v','a','t'];
var input = ['violet', 'EXTRA 2', 'very','auto','tom','tim', 'EXTRA 1'];
input.sort(function(a, b) {
  // are the strings equal?
  if(a === b) {
    return 0;
  }

  // if they are not equal, compare the first letters
  //  against the custom sort order
  var indexOfA = order.indexOf(a[0]);
  var aInList = indexOfA >= 0;

  var indexOfB = order.indexOf(b[0]);
  var bInList = indexOfB >= 0;

  // if the first letter of neither string is in the list,
  //  compare alphabetically
  if(!aInList && !bInList) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  } else if(!aInList) {
    // the first letter of only a is not in the list
    return 1;
  } else if(!bInList) { 
    // the first letter of only b is not in the list
    return -1;
  } else if(indexOfA === indexOfB) {
    // the first letter of a and b are both in the list
    //  and they are the same
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  } else {
    // the first letters are different; sort by first letter
    return indexOfA - indexOfB;
  }
})
```

If you can guarantee that the first letter is in your sort order array, you can omit the `if(indexOfX === -1)` checks.

Comment: You could just `return indexOfA - indexOfB;` for letters in list, instead of using if clauses.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I made it verbose because I wanted to show explicitly how comparators work.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, you have to compare the strings themselves if letters are in list and `indexOfA == indexOfB`. Otherwise the chunks starting with the same letter will not get sorted.

Comment: You are quite right, thanks. And I decided it is actually easier to read using your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea to omit the `a == b` case for the sake of brevity. This should have a performance impact on big lists.

Comment: Yes - and I didn't actually know about `localeCompare` before this. I guess I always tried to autocomplete `"str".comp...` in the console and gave up when I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at js it might be further optimized but this must work for you.

```
var outArray = new Array();
var inArray = [ "Zpple", "Zuto", "tim", "tom", "very", "tiolet", "Ztest" ];


inArray.forEach(function(input, i){

    outArray.push(input);
    delete inArray[i];

    var startChar = input.charAt(0);

    inArray.forEach(function(input, i){

        if(input.startsWith(startChar)){
            outArray.push(input);
            delete inArray[i];      
        }       

    });


});
```

Output:

```
   ["Zpple", "Zuto", "Ztest", "tim", "tom", "tiolet", "very"]
```